# Update multiple columns with AVG() in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing an issue when trying to update two columns with the same value.

Normally, when updating 2 columns with same value, the common way for MySQL is :

```
UPDATE Table
SET field1 = value,
SET field2 = value
WHERE conditions;
```

But when working on this code hereby with the 2 average calculations, I am stuck and cannot find the issue in the syntax.

```
update table1 
set field1 = (SELECT avg(calculation) from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1),
set field2 = (SELECT avg(calculation) from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1)
where id = 123;
```

Any advice?

Comment: What error does that code give you? probably something because you duplicated the `set`. Without that, it's fine, and any half-decent query optimiser will optimise it away. To avoid the written repetition, a CTE or subquery seems ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
update table1 t1 cross join
       (select avg(calculation) as avg_c from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1) t2
    set t1.field1 = t2.avg_c,
        t1.field2 = t2.avg_c
    where t1.id = 123;
```

Your method is also fine, but only one `set` is needed:

```
update table1 
    set field1 = (SELECT avg(calculation) from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1),
        field2 = (SELECT avg(calculation) from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1)
    where id = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `SET` only once at the beginning of the assignments.
You don't need to calculate the average twice, because this will do it:

```
update table1 
set field1 = (SELECT avg(calculation) from table2 where id = 123 and year = 1),
    field2 = field1
where id = 123;
```

MySql uses the changed value of `field1` in the assignment to `field2`.
You can find more about it here: [13.2.13 UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)